# How can I get created GRPC ManagedChannel and stub again?

Tags: java, grpc, host, channel, stub

```
ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(host).usePlaintext().build();
Grpc.Stub stub = Grpc.newStub(managedChannel);
```

I used this stub for a process and this method is finished. Another service call this method and I wanna get this stub for another process for the same host without opening new channel and stub. How can I do? Is there any method like `stub.get(host)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean it is another process (i.e. another service) on the same host then it must be using another port and you will need to create another channel with that port number. There is no `stub.get(host)` .